# Android SQLite weird behavior

Tags: android, sqlite

Can anybody explain why:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Definition;");
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Definition (txt TEXT);");
```

works well, but

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Definition; CREATE TABLE Definition (txt TEXT);");
```

does **NOTHING** (no table "Definition" exists after this exec).

*(db is instance of SQLiteDatabase)*

P.S. In iOS both variants do absolutely the same. As well as in SQLite manager (Firefox add-on).

Answer (score 4):

SQLite doesn't want to execute several commands at a time. I write all the commands into a text file, read lines until ";" is met and execute one by one in a loop until readLine is null;

```
List<String> sqlExpressions = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    // read table creation sql script from the file
    InputStream inStream = mContext.getResources().getAssets().open("createTables.sql");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF-8"));
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        if(line.lastIndexOf(";") > 0) {
            sqlExpressions.add(sb.toString());
    sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
reader.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.d("DB_Creation", e.getMessage());
}

for (String sqlExpr : sqlExpressions) {
     database.execSQL(sqlExpr);
}
```